# Playing video in Android in overlapped view

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wish to play a video file in my application when user performs a certain action. I googled for code samples that do it, but all samples I found play video inside a pre-defined view in the application. What I need is different: launch video player on top of application, in an overlapped full-screen window/view.

I tried the following code, but video window does not come up:

```
VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this /* my activity */);
videoView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(videoView.getContext()));
videoView.setVideoPath(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
videoView.bringToFront();
```

What should I do to make the player show up?

Answer (score 0):

try to make an activity that shows videoview and works as dialog. activity as dialog is simple to code and you can get samples easily. just set theme as dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Change WRAP_CONTENT to FILL_PARENT